# Adding third-party cookie exception to Cypress configuration

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, automated-tests, cypress

Using Cypress, JavaScript end to end testing framework, is there a supported mechanism to add a third-party cookie exception, or some other Chromium preference (or Electron/ if not using e.g. `--browser chromium`)?

I have found a mechanism to do this but it involves wrapping the browser executable, effectively a man-in-the-middle between Cypress and the "browser" binary.

Answer (score 0):

Presently, Cypress does not provide direct support for this.  There is a standing change request to provide API support for this and other Chromium/browser preferences: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3671

A solution I've created is to run Cypress with a custom browser which pre-populates the Chromium user data directory ("profile") with these preferences: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3671#issuecomment-549660119

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

USER_DATA_DIR=`cut -d "=" -f 2 <<< ${*: -2:1}`
mkdir $USER_DATA_DIR/Default > $USER_DATA_DIR/Default/Preferences
cat << END_Preferences > $USER_DATA_DIR/Default/Preferences
{
"profile":{"content_settings":{"exceptions":{"cookies":{"example.com,*":{"setting":1}}}}}
}
END_Preferences
exec chromium $@
```